# What determines the gear score new things drop at?

Tags: ghost-recon-breakpoint

I've been playing Ghost Recon Breakpoint and noticed that there have been points where the level that new gear drops at stagnates for a bit before beginning to increase. (I've gotten stuck temporarily at gear scores of 50, 90, 130).

I was typically holding a higher level item in my inventory (not equipped) to "boost" my score since I assumed that was how it determined drops (your highest level possible - like Destiny). However, I started to notice that I would get stuck at spots before getting new gear.

> Example: I had all level 130-131 gear *except* a sniper equipped at 121. I was unable to get any gear to drop above 131. I was XP 21 at the time as well. I equipped a new gun (130) to replace the sniper at the same time I hit XP 22 and started finding level 134 drops so I can't 100% say if it was one or the other.

I haven't been able to determine if it's related directly to what's equipped or maybe even your XP level. At this point based I'm assuming it's related to equipped gear but I'm looking to see if anyone has more concrete knowledge or evidence.

**What determines the level that new gear (weapons or armor) drops at?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with a fair amount of confidence, I can say that it appears to be the equipped gear that dictates the newest drops you receive.

I stagnated again at 145 and with 2 equipped items still at 137, and without leveling up but equipping new higher level gear to replace the low-level items, I began to receive drops at 148 almost immediately.

There doesn't appear to be any trend to when items begin to stagnate other than still having low-level gear equipped.